# Difference in usage of きる and ぬく attached to verb 連用形

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the `きる` and `ぬく` forms, which are attached against verb 連用形?
As I understand,they both indicate 'extreme effort' or 'trying to the last'

Comment: You mean to ask about きる (not きり) and ぬく when attached to the 連用形 of a verb, no?

Comment: True.Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1137141731) was convincing, at least for me.

Verb(連用形)きる is used when you are "Completing it till 100%".

- Example sentence: 「長編小説を読みきる」

Verb(連用形)ぬく is used when you are "Endure something and achieve it".

- Example sentence: 「悩みぬいて決断した」

Comment: I might add that 「～～きる」 sounds more result-oriented while 「～～ぬく」 sounds more process-oriented.

Comment: I like what @lélecteur said.  When きる is used for 悩む、I'd expect the next word to be 結果。e.g. 悩みきった結果